# Why does an insert query cause my dataflow pipeline to stop processing database inserts?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline(streaming) that is processing large amounts of inserts throughout the day and inserting them into Cloud SQL. I am trying to populate another table with existing data, but when I try to insert into those tables it causes the pipeline to stop inserting. The second I stop executing the query, the inserts continue to insert without issue.

I've tried other queries on my database, but only the inserts cause it to stop processing the inserts.

My insert query is:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2, firstUsed, lastUsed)
SELECT DISTINCT c3, c4, MIN(created), MAX(created) FROM t1 WHERE created 
<= '2018-12-01 23:59:59' GROUP BY c3, c4
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastUsed = VALUES(lastUsed)
```

The exception I receive on Google Cloud is:

```
Processing stuck in step ParDo(ProcessDatabaseEvent) for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:557)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:735)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:674)
  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:966)
  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1165)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:937)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1116)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1066)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1396)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1051)
  at mypardo.processElement(StatsCollector.java:173)
  at mypardo.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
timestamp 2019-04-04T17:40:01.724Z
logger com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowOperationContext
severity WARNING
worker myworker
step ParDo(ProcessDatabaseEvent)
thread 34
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Adding Database Schema

t1: (approx 10 million records)

```
c1          varchar(255)  NO   PRI NULL    
c2          varchar(255)  NO   PRI NULL     
c3          varchar(255)  YES  NULL    
c4          varchar(255)  YES  NULL    
c5          varchar(255)  YES  NULL    
c6          varchar(255)  YES  NULL    
created     datetime      YES  NULL
```

t2:

```
c1         varchar(255) NO   PRI NULL    
c2         varchar(255) NO   PRI NULL    
firstUsed  datetime     YES      NULL    
lastUsed   datetime     YES      NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use group by you don't need  distinct  and you should not use values(lastUsed) in ON DUPLICATE  clase but t1.lastUsed

```
  INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2, firstUsed, lastUsed)
  SELECT c3, c4, MIN(created), MAX(created) 
  FROM t1 
  WHERE created <= '2018-12-01 23:59:59' 
  GROUP BY c3, c4
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastUsed = t1.lastUsed
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimizations, I'll switch to using that. Unfortunately, the query still stalls my dataflow stream.

Comment: which data type is the created  table  ?

Comment: both tables are a mix of varchars and datetimes.

Comment: then add  the related  tables schema please

Comment: Added to the main post